# permission denied while executing START-DFS.SH in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, unix, hadoop, bigdata

suresh@suresh-laptop:/$ usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin/start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
15/02/01 00:24:52 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on []
suresh@localhost's password: 
**localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs': Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access`/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/logs': No such file or directory**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check these commands:

```
sudo adduser suresh sudo
chown -R /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0
chmod -R 755 /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0
```