# Permission Denied: Verifying Hadoop dfs

Tags: hadoop, installation

Even though this question is going to be an exact replica of another, I am still willing to ask it - since none of the other similar questions (and answers) on StackOverflow and AskUbuntu have helped me out. I am a total newbie, and trying to learn Hive from a TutorialsPoint tutorial.

I've followed the installation guide of JDK 1.7 and Hadoop given in this link: [Hive - Installation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/hive_installation.htm) to its helm, and got stuck at the Step II: Verifying Hadoop dfs.

On running `start-dfs.sh` after formatting namenode at home directory, I'm getting the following output:

```
neil@neil-VirtualBox:~$ start-dfs.sh
15/08/04 19:42:01 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
neil@localhost's password: 
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/local/hadoop/logs': Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access `/usr/local/hadoop/logs': No such file or directory
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-neil-namenode-neil-VirtualBox.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-neil-namenode-neil-VirtualBox.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open `/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-neil-namenode-neil-VirtualBox.out' for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-neil-namenode-neil-VirtualBox.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-neil-namenode-neil-VirtualBox.out: No such file or directory
```

I've tried each and every solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211848/hadoop-start-dfs-sh-permission-denied) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255344/permission-denied-while-executing-start-dfs-sh-in-ubuntu?rq=1) without progressing any further.

Also, when I run the 'hadoop version' command, it gives the following output:

```
Hadoop 2.7.0
Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r d4c8d4d4d203c934e8074b31289a28724c0842cf
Compiled by jenkins on 2015-04-10T18:40Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum a9e90912c37a35c3195d23951fd18f
This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.0.jar
```

which is bizarre, as I had uninstalled Hadoop 2.7.0 completely before installing Hadoop 2.4.0 as given in the tutorial link. I'm also running Java 1.7.0_79.

I've been stuck on this for 2 days now, and have been crawling the internet since then. Please give me a solution, or links which I can use to understand my way out. Since I'm a complete newbie to installing Hadoop, any form of help is much appreciated. I will also update the questions according to your feedback.

Thanks,

Souradeep

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: Start the services using root user

Answer (score 0):

For your `start-dfs.sh` problem, try this:

**Step 1:** Check whether the folder `/usr/local/hadoop/logs` exists. If it exists go to step 3. If not, do step 2.

```
ls -l /usr/local/hadoop/logs
```

**Step 2:** Create the folder manually.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/hadoop/logs
```

**Step 3:** Change permission and ownership.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/hadoop/logs
sudo chown -R hadoopusername:hadoopgroupname /usr/local/hadoop/logs
```

> **NOTE:** Change **hadoopusername** to your hadoop user and **hadoopgroupname** to your hadoop group. In my case, my user and group name was **hduser** and **hadoop** respectively. So my command
>   was like: **sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop ...**

Now, start hadoop processes using `start-dfs.sh`.

For your `hadoop -version` problem, try removing lib files related to 2.7.0 or remove 2.7.0 related PATH entries in `/home/hadoopuser/.bashrc`.